# Python-VISSIM COM Interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new with Python, and I have a problem with Python-Vissim connection. The problem is that when I'm starting running my python file, Vissim starts to open and load my model (network and layout). After it's done with loading, Vissim just closed itself. I don't know what am I doing wrong? I hope that somebody can help me with this issue.

Here's my code:

```
import win32com.client as com
```

class COM:

```
#region Vissim connection

 Inpx_path = ''
 Layx_path = ''

 def __init__(self):
     self.Inpx_path = r'D:\\User\\Model\\Hein.inpx'
     self.Layx_path = r'D:\\User\\Model\\Hein.layx'

 def startVissim(self):
     try:
         Vissim = com.dynamic.Dispatch('Vissim.Vissim.110') 
         return Vissim
     except Exception as e: 
         print(e)


 def loadNetwork(self, vissim):
     try:
         Net = vissim.LoadNet(self.Inpx_path)
         return Net
     except Exception as e: 
         print(e)


 def loadLayout(self, vissim):
     try:
         Layout = vissim.LoadLayout(self.Layx_path)
         return Layout
     except Exception as e: 
         print(e)

vissim = COM().startVissim()
net = COM().loadNetwork(vissim)
layout = COM().loadLayout(vissim)
```

**NOTE:** vissim, net, and layout is outside of class COM

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I remember from a PTV COM training course, it might help if you try the following steps:

1. Make a copy of the desktop shortcut for the version for Vissim you are using.
2. Right click on the new shortcut, go to properties, and add *-automation* to the end of the target as shown below.
3. Open an instance of Vissim using this shortcut, then try running your code. It should open the model in the already open instance, and should remain open after your code finishes.

[image]

If that doesn't help, I'd recommend getting in touch with PTV, either via technical support or a post on the 'PTV Vissim Forum' group on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code, try just calling the "vissim" object (new line shown below). This worked in my code to keep it from closing. I believe it puts the program in a holding state waiting for the next command; otherwise, the software reaches then end of code and closes.

```
vissim = COM().startVissim()
net = COM().loadNetwork(vissim)
layout = COM().loadLayout(vissim)

vissim ## new line of code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior as your script has ended, therefore the Vissim closes. For evaluation purposes, you could perhaps as a while loop at the end of the program so that technically the program would keep running, and therefore vissim would not close.

However, the above approach would not allow you to interact with the Simulation with python anymore. I use it just for evaluation purposes, if really needed.

If you'd like to keep Vissim running and still be able to interact with it, I'd suggest using the Python IDLE. Either you could manually type in all of your code in there each time, or alternatively, simply import your script file. The Python instance would still be running, therefore the Vissim application would not close, you can still invoke COM functions to interact with Vissim via Python.

To import your script file:

```
from foo import *
```

Assuming the above script file you've shared is called foo.py, and you're in the same directory, this should load Vissim, not close and allow you to add additional code.